# Setting GHCi prompt inside multiline blocks

Tags: haskell, ghci

GHCi's prompt can be set as follows, which is in my `.ghci`:

```
:set prompt "λ> "
```

However, a different prompt appears in multiline blocks, and I can't figure out how to change it. It is completely unreadable if too many modules are imported:

```
λ> :{
Prelude Control.Arrow Control.Applicative Control.Monad Control.Concurrent Control.Concurrent.Async Control.Parallel Data.String Data.Char Data.List Data.Maybe Data.Monoid Control.Monad.IO.Class|
```

Is there a way to set this secondary prompt? Alternatively, are there other good ways to run Haskell interactively where multiline expressions are displayed in a more friendly manner?

Comment: I know you can do `:set +m` for much nicer multiline statements (more IPython-y, not quite as nice though), but I'm giving a +1 because I really want to know how to get rid of the annoying module prefix during multiline statements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In GHC 7.8.1 and newer, you can change the continuation prompt using `:set prompt2`.

See [GHC #7509](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7509).

Comment: So the feature isn't available in stable GHC yet? Oh well, I guess I can wait.

Answer (score 17):

You can't use `prompt2` for GHC 8.2.1 and newer anymore because interface is changed. Previously it was:

```
   :set prompt <prompt>        set the prompt used in GHCi
   :set prompt2 <prompt>       set the continuation prompt used in GHCi
```

Now it's:

```
   :set prompt <prompt>        set the prompt used in GHCi
   :set prompt-cont <prompt>   set the continuation prompt used in GHCi
   :set prompt-function <expr> set the function to handle the prompt
   :set prompt-cont-function <expr> set the function to handle the continuation prompt
```

Some typical usages of these functions (just type in your GHCi or add in `~/.ghc/ghci.conf` to apply settings globally):

```
:set prompt      λ: 
:set prompt-cont λ|
```

or

```
:set prompt      ghci> 
:set prompt-cont ghci|
```

> **Note:** space at the end of each line

Comment: Works fine with `:set prompt-cont "   | "` for multiline prompt

Comment: can you link to documentation?

Comment: @AaronHall you can just write `:?` in ghci to see list of available commands. But here is the link to documentation: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:set%20prompt-cont